# Join Table and maintain same amount of rows based on value in a column

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT t.USER_ID, c.CODE 
FROM TRANSACTIONS t 
INNER JOIN USER u ON t.USER_ID = u.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN COMPANY c ON c.CODE = u.CODE
```

which returns this result set:

```
USER ID     CODE
-----------------
01          100
02          100
03          100
03          120
```

Then I have table `INTERACTIONS` (for example), which lists every interaction with code:

```
CODE     INTERACTION     WORKED_YN
-----------------------------------
100      Sample 01       Y
100      Sample 02       Y
120      Sample 03       N
120      Sample 04       N
etc.
```

The `CODE` column values should always have the same outcome (ie. 100 will always be Y and 120 will always be N).

How do I join table `INTERACTIONS` without having every interaction, so that I can have the following output:

```
USER ID     CODE    WORKED_YN
-----------------------------
01          100     Y
02          100     Y
03          100     Y
03          120     N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need `INTERACTIONS.INTERACTION` column in your result set you can just subquery your `INTERACTIONS` table to get distinct records omitting that column:

```
SELECT t.USER_ID, c.CODE 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CODE, WORKED_YN, USER_ID FROM TRANSACTIONS) t 
INNER JOIN USER u ON t.USER_ID = u.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN COMPANY c ON c.CODE = u.CODE
```